# Remove #! from url in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to understand how to remove #! from the url in angularjs using ng-route .
Can please someone help me with the exact steps I need to follow in order to remove #!.

Here is the code

index.html

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script src="a02.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  Hello there
  <hr>
  <a href="#test">Click Me </a>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

a02.js

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", ['ngRoute']);

  app.config(["$routeProvider",function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/test',{
        template:"<strong>It's routing template</strong>"
    })
}]);
```

My requirement is when click on click me link it should display

> It's routing template.

But when browser loads index.html the url is coming as

```
http://localhost:3000/index.html#!/
```

and when I click on Click Me link the url is coming as

```
http://localhost:3000/index.html#!/#test
```

I want this url and link to be work without #!.

Answer (score 3):

in your js router file you need to add:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); 
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and in your index html file (head tag) you need to add:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Why we need to add $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); ?